# Sum Total of Row and Column in HTML Table using Javascript Excluding First and Last

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I'm trying to take an HTML table that was created from a Javascript 2D array and I am trying to get sum each row and column in the table excluding the top row and first TD in each row.

```
var pandlarray = [
[2017-04,0,-118.05,-181.21,-400.43,0]
[2017-05,1510.27,-35.34,-180.99,-351.46,0]
];
// BEGIN - Create HTML table from javascript array.
function makeTableHTML(myArray) {
  var result = "<table id='pandltable'>";
  result += "<tr><td>Month</td><td>Revenue</td><td>MaterialCost</td><td>Utilities</td><td>Labor</td><td>Margin</td></tr>";
  for(var a=0; a<myArray.length; a++) {
      result += "<tr>";
      for(var j=0; j<myArray[a].length; j++){
        if (myArray[a][j] === 0) {
          result += "<td>"+0+"</td>";
        }
        else {
          result += "<td>"+myArray[a][j]+"</td>";
        }
      }
      result += "</tr>";
  }
  result += "<tr><td><strong>Total<strong></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></table>";
  return result;
  }
  document.write(makeTableHTML(pandlarray));
  // END - Create HTML table from javascript array.
  // BEGIN - Total row and columns for pandltable.
  $("#pandltable tr:not(:first,:last)  td:last-child").text(function(){
    var t = 0;
    $(this).prevAll().each(function(){
        t += t += parseFloat($(this).text(),0) || 0;
    });
    return t;
  });

  $("#pandltable tr:last td:not(:first)").text(function(i){
    var t = 0;
    $(this).parent().prevAll().find("td:nth-child("+(i + 2)+")").each(function(){
        t += parseFloat($(this).text(),0) || 0;
    });
    return t;
  });
  // END - Total row and columns for pandltable.
```

Not the most beautiful code I know but this is what I have to work with. The values that are returning right now to the total of each row and column are nowhere near right and they are also showing repeating decimals. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Made a few changes to your array definition and make table function. Assigned class 'first' to month column to prevent it being added in each row. And used .toFixed() function to limit totals to two decimal points. There is error in first function - calculate total for each row - t += t += -- this might be typo.

```
    var pandlarray = ["2017-04,0,-118.05,-181.21,-400.43,0",
    "2017-05,1510.27,-35.34,-180.99,-351.46,0"
    ];
    // BEGIN - Create HTML table from javascript array.
    function makeTableHTML(myArray) {
      var result = "<table id='pandltable'>";
      result += "<tr><td width='20%'>Month</td><td width='20%'>Revenue</td><td width='20%'>MaterialCost</td><td width='20%'>Utilities</td><td width='20%'>Labor</td><td width='20%'>Margin</td></tr>";
      for(var a=0; a<myArray.length; a++) {
      var thisRow = myArray[a].split(",");

          result += "<tr>";
          for(var j=0; j<thisRow.length; j++){
            if (j === 0) {
              result += "<td class='first'>"+thisRow[j]+"</td>";
            }
            else {
              result += "<td>"+thisRow[j]+"</td>";
            }
          }
          result += "</tr>";
      }
      result +="<tr><td colspan=6>&nbsp;</td> </tr>";
      result += "<tr><td><strong>Total<strong></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></table>";
      return result;
      }

      document.write(makeTableHTML(pandlarray));
      // END - Create HTML table from javascript array.
      // BEGIN - Total row and columns for pandltable.
      $("#pandltable tr:not(:first,:last)  td:last-child").text(function(){
        var t = 0;
        $(this).prevUntil(".first").each(function(){
             t += parseFloat($(this).text(),2) || 0;
        });
        t = t.toFixed(2);
        return t;
      });

      $("#pandltable tr:last td:not(:first)").text(function(i){
        var t = 0;
        $(this).parent().prevAll().find("td:nth-child("+(i + 2)+")").each(function(){
            t += parseFloat($(this).text(),0) || 0;
        });
        t = t.toFixed(2);
        return t;
      });
      // END - Total row and columns for pandltable.
```